# How to use if condition in javascript id selector. I want not to run 'window.addEventListener' on particular id click. Here is my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
   <div class="quiz1" id="quiz1">   
        <h1>Which item below are you need of most?</h1>
        <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="more_cli" value="I need more clients">I need more clients </li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="more_cli" value="I need to increase my revenue per client">I need to increase my revenue per client </li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="more_cli" value="Other">Other </li>
        <li><input type="text" name="other_quiz1" id="other_quiz1_text" value=""></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="remain"> <p>3 question remaining</p> </div>
    </div>      

    <div class="quiz2" id="quiz2">
        <h1>Tell us about your work status as a stylist.</h1>
        <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="about_cli" value="I'm self employed">I'm self employed</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="about_cli" value="I'm an employee">I'm an employee</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="about_cli" value="I'm currently not working as a stylist">I'm currently not working as a stylist</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="remain"> <p>2 question remaining</p> </div>
    </div>      


    <div class="quiz3" id="quiz3">
        <h1>Are you working full or part time as a stylist?</h1>
        <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="work_cli" value="I'm part time">I'm part time</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="work_cli" value="I'm full time">I'm full time</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="work_cli" value="I'm currently not working as a stylist">I'm currently not working as a stylist</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="remain"> <p>1 question remaining</p> </div>
    </div>      

    <div class="quiz4" id="quiz4">
        <h1>Which zip code do you work in?</h1>
        <ul>
        <li><input type="text" name="other_quiz1" id="other_quiz1_text1"></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="remain"> <p>0 question remaining</p> </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#other_quiz1_text').hide();
        $('#quiz2').hide();
        $('#quiz3').hide();
        $('#quiz4').hide();
        $('input:radio[name="more_cli"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Other'){
        $('#other_quiz1_text').fadeIn();       
    } else {
        $('#other_quiz1_text').fadeOut();  

    }

    $('#qzn1').click(function(){
        $('#quiz1').fadeOut();
        $('#quiz2').fadeIn();

    });

    $('#qzn2').click(function(){
        $('#quiz2').fadeOut();
        $('#quiz3').fadeIn();

    });

    $('#qzn3').click(function(){
        $('#quiz3').fadeOut();
        $('#quiz4').fadeIn();

    });

    $('#qzp4').click(function(){
        $('#quiz4').fadeOut();
        $('#quiz3').fadeIn();

    });

    $('#qzp3').click(function(){
        $('#quiz3').fadeOut();
        $('#quiz2').fadeIn();

    });

    $('#qzp2').click(function(){
        $('#quiz2').fadeOut();
        $('#quiz1').fadeIn();

    });   

$('#qzn4').click(function(){

    var url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/ajax';
    var option1=$('input:radio[name="more_cli"]:checked').val();
    var optxt = $('#other_quiz1_text').val();
    var option2=$('input:radio[name="about_cli"]:checked').val();
    var option3=$('input:radio[name="work_cli"]:checked').val();
    var option4 = $('#other_quiz1_text1').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {'option1': option1, 'optxt': optxt, 'option2': option2, 'option3': option3, 'option4': option4, 'status':'optn', 'current_user' : '<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>'},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //return data;
            if(data != ''){
                window.location.href = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/get-started'; 
            }
        }
    });

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
    var msg ="Is it something we said or didn't say, or do you just hate us?     There are lots of benefits in our free profile.  If you're not interested please let us know what we can do to improve."
  var confirmationMessage = msg;

  (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE

    ipsrv();
  return confirmationMessage;                            //Webkit, Safari, Chrome
});     
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have to tried to read Jquery Documentation atleast?

Comment: Please! Please format your question

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what the question is, but it can probably be solved by moving the event handler to the parent containing all these divs. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var smn = true;

window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
if(smn == true) {
var msg ="Are You Sure?"
ipsrv();
return msg; } }


$('#qzn4').click(function(){
smn = false;
/**CODE**/ 
}

});

</script>
```

I didnt use but hope this help.